# Excel VBA script cause not responding everytime it turned on

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a script that will automatically copy value from sheet FORM and paste to specific sheet that listed on a table of sheet CONFIG with specific column and range for the sheet name and the corresponding column on sheet FORM. However, everytime I turned on the script its cause Not responding, I have tried to change the value that must imported from CONFIG sheet to the real integer but the problem still there.

```
Sub importvalue()
    Dim sheetname, sheetcolumn As String
    Dim isheet, iform, output_idx, output_stt As Integer
    
    
    Dim confsheet As Worksheet
    Dim formsheet As Worksheet
    Dim outputsheet As Worksheet
    
    
    Set formsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FORM")
    Set confsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CONFIG")

    isheet = 2
    
    Dim thoigian As String
    thoigian = formsheet.Range("E1").Value & "-" & formsheet.Range("G1").Value
    While isheet <= 5
        confsheet.Range("E1").Value = isheet
        sheetname = confsheet.Range("J" & isheet).Value
        sheetcolumn = confsheet.Range("K" & isheet).Value
        Set outputsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname)
        iform = 2
        output_idx = outputsheet.Range("A1").Value
        output_stt = outputsheet.Range("C1").Value
        outputsheet.Range("A" & output_idx).Value = thoigian
        outputsheet.Range("B" & output_idx).Value = output_stt

        While iform <= 115
            confsheet.Range("E1").Value = iform
            outputcolumn = confsheet.Range("D" & iform).Value
            formrow = confsheet.Range("C" & iform).Value
            If Not formrow = "" Then
                outputsheet.Range(outputcolumn & output_idx).Value = formsheet.Range(sheetcolumn & formrow).Value
                iform = iform + 1
            End If
        Wend
        isheet = isheet + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

EDIT 1: This is the dropbox link the for sample that I'm working with: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjf5xce20o2f0tl/SAMPLE.xlsm?dl=0

EDIT 2: Thank you @FunThomas and @FaneDuru for pointing out my problem.

```
Sub importvalue()
    Dim sheetname, sheetcolumn As String
    Dim isheet, iform, output_idx, output_stt As Integer
    
    
    Dim confsheet As Worksheet
    Dim formsheet As Worksheet
    Dim outputsheet As Worksheet
    
    
    Set formsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FORM")
    Set confsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CONFIG")

    isheet = 2
    
    Dim thoigian As String
    thoigian = formsheet.Range("E1").Value & "-" & formsheet.Range("G1").Value
    While isheet <= 5
        confsheet.Range("E1").Value = isheet
        sheetname = confsheet.Range("J" & isheet).Value
        sheetcolumn = confsheet.Range("K" & isheet).Value
        Set outputsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname)
        iform = 2
        output_idx = outputsheet.Range("A1").Value
        output_stt = outputsheet.Range("C1").Value
        outputsheet.Range("A" & output_idx).Value = thoigian
        outputsheet.Range("B" & output_idx).Value = output_stt

        While iform <= 115
            confsheet.Range("E1").Value = iform
            outputcolumn = confsheet.Range("D" & iform).Value
            formrow = confsheet.Range("C" & iform).Value
            If Not formrow = "" Then
                outputsheet.Range(outputcolumn & output_idx).Value = formsheet.Range(sheetcolumn & formrow).Value
                
            End If
        iform = iform + 1
        Wend
        isheet = isheet + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand the complete logic of your code, but once you are in the inner while loop and `formrow = ""`, you are trapped in an endless loop because `iform` stays the same value

Comment: It stays in an infinite loop in case of `formrow = ""`. As stated above, `iform` will not be incremented. Please move `iform = iform + 1` just before `Wend` line...